# Is there an easy way to let a html button execute a python function

Tags: python, html, button

I have a python function that creates a .txt file with an output / results and saves it in my project directory. Now i have a html js files where i take that data from the .txt file and i use it and display the data.

Now my problem is, i want to have a button that executes the python script and creates fresh data depending on a variable.

Is there an easy way to do it.

I am quite new to programming web applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use frameworks like flask. with flask you just paste your function with a root that will be executed when you go on that root.
just set Form action to your root and then make your method there like it:

```
<form method="POST" action={{ url_for('your_function') }}>
<div style="text-align: center;">
<H1>Admin panel login </H1> <br>
Username <input type = "text" name= "username" /> <br>
Password <input type = "password" name = "password" /> <br>
<input type = "submit">
</div>
</form>
```

then in your python file :

```
def your_function():
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Browser has no permission to read local file system. So you must serve the .txt file first.

**foo.txt**

```
Foo
Bar
Baz
```

**foo.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
<script>
    fetch("foo.txt").then(x => x.text()).then(text => document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerText = text)
</script>
</html>
```

**Start HTTP Server in same directory of `foo.txt` and `foo.html`**

```
python3 -mhttp.server 8888
```

Then open `http://localhost:8888/foo.html` to see the result.